# Convert react-js Material-tables headerStyle Columns to Row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying some gradient designs on material table ,although im able to render right colour combination on rows but on title of the table im getting column based result,i've attached screenshot of my output

[image: Result of my code]

here's the code for same

```
function RowStyling() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Row Styling Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      options={{
        rowStyle: {
            background: 'linear-gradient(to right,#137a8b,#30e4fb)',
           border: '2px white solid',
           borderRadius: '50px'
        },
         headerStyle: {
                background: 'linear-gradient(to right,#137a8b,#30e4fb)',
                color: '#FFF',
              }
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

what changes i need to do to make it look like rows,
you can rafer material-table styling [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling)

Comment: I also gone through this problem where I can't find a solution to this but I do a little hacky way that I override the css property of that class that works fine for me. I override the class of MTableToolbar-root-5 in the css file and linked it to the react.

Comment: can you elaborate the same in answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I think this is a bug on `material-table` library. I tried in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-forked-8o6l6?file=/src/AppTable.js) codesandbox example to make header color with the same rows linear gradient but I found that:

1. if in `headerStyle` you set `background: "linear-gradient(to right,#137a8b,#30e4fb)"`, this style will be applied to header cells, and not to the header (this is your case). Infact, by inspecting the element you will see:

[image]

the linear gradient is applied to the `th` style and not to the `tr` style as expected.

2. same thing happens if you set `backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to right,#137a8b,#30e4fb)"`.
3. if you set `backgroundColor: "red"` same result: style will applied to cells, not to header (but with a fixed color seems that all the header has the same color :) ).

Note: I tried also to wrap MaterialTable into Material UI `ThemeProvider` overriding css class but I didn't get any result :(

**EDIT**

To override a class using `ThemeProvider` you can:

1. Define a theme object and override tha class you want to override in this way:

   ```
   const Theme = {
    palette: {
      primary: {
        contrastText: "#FF0000",  // this is just a color (red for example)
        dark: "#FF0000",
        main: "#FF0000",
        light: "#FF0000"
     }
   },
   overrides: {   // in this object you can override css classes
    MuiTableHead: {   // overriding of MuiTableHead
      root: {  //overriding root
        background: "black"
      }
    }
   }
   };
   ```
2. pass this object to `createMuiTheme` function:

   ```
   const theme = createMuiTheme(Theme);
   ```
3. Wrap `MaterialTable` in `ThemeProvider` component (passing `theme`) in this way:

   ```
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MaterialTable
       ....
       />
   </ThemeProvider>
   ```

But also in this way, even if `background: "black"` is in component style

[image]

background remains red (as setted in `headerStyle`)

Comment: yes i saw that,even with background colour tag it will reflect to <th> tag,try adding border styles in headerstyle you will get to know that its not working with backgroundColor as well ,here's the border css  border: '2px white solid',
                borderRadius: '10px'

Comment: I've added some changes in sandbox for same issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-forked-ot9jp

Comment: Yes @Aniket everything you put on `headerStyle` will be reflected on cells , not on header (so maybe should be `headerCellStyle` :) )

Comment: tried headerCellStyle as well,still not reflecting on tr tag

Comment: @Aniket  I think is a bug or something that is not yet implemented in this library...

Comment: Yes,thanks but how about overriding another component or css in it?like tableHead in material-table components ?

Comment: @Aniket material-table accepts overriding by using Material UI theme overriding. If you want I can update codesandbox to show you how you can do that, but I tried and override will be applied to the style component but not rendered (I don't know why :( )

Comment: Yes,can u elaborate the same in sandbox? im new to material-ui

Comment: @Aniket I have edited my answer to explain what I wrote to override css class (and updated codesandbox) :)

Comment: tried with overrinding using theme provider as well,still not working

Comment: @Aniket yep, no way to override it (for that reason I thought that there is a bug on library). Reading better the [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling) docs, he said that to override all the header style you should use `column.headerStyle` but how to use it? I tried several times but I failed...

Comment: Yes,will research more about it,thanks for your time

Comment: No problem @Aniket. I try to understand how it works and in case I will update my answer

Comment: Found a solution for same,i've added an answer

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the element first and found its classes,and defined it in withStyles function of material UI to override its css ,like below code .

```
const styles = withStyles ({
  root: {
    //display: "flex"
    "& .MuiTypography-h6": {//Title in MTable
      color: "#545454"
    },
    '& .MuiPaper-root': {//table header root,where title and toolbox relies 
      color: 'black',
      transition: 'box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderRadius: ' 10px;',
      padding: '10px'
    },
    "& .MuiTableRow-head": {//title columns
      background: "linear-gradient(to right,#137a8b,#30e4fb) !important",
      border: '2px white solid',
      borderRadius: '10px',

    },
    "& .MuiTableCell-head": {//table cells,all
      background: "none"
    }
}
});
```

After that wrap this material table in div tag with css class like :

```
    <div className={classes.root}>
             <MaterialTable/>
      </div>
```

Note:You can use makeStyles in functional component and withStyles in class based component